# How to perform Synchronous Programming

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am not a native English speaker, so please ignore my mistakes.

I am using NodeJs and want to **insert bulk data into the MySQL database**.

I have an insertion query inside a nested loop and want to use async-await in the insertion query in a **nested loop** to perform the synchronous insertion and wait till the loop completes.

```
for(i=0; i<100; i++){
    for(j=0; j<100; j++){
        // mysql insert query
    }
}
```

Comment: Here you go. https://zellwk.com/blog/async-await-in-loops/ . Read this and you should be able to achieve you're goal.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to push all promises(async calls) in an array using a loop and then use methods like `Promise.all() or Promise.allSettled()` to execute them all.

```
let promiseArr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   promiseArr.push(asyncAction)
}
Promise.all(promiseArr).then((res => {
    // success case
}, err => {
    // error case
});
```

docs: [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) [Promise.settledAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled)